# Linking OpenCV 2.3 program in Mac OS X Lion: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: opencv, cmake, x86-64, ld

I'm having a problem when trying to compile the program in [this tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) from the OpenCV 2.3 official documentation. I have created the CMakeList.txt like it's said in the link. Well, it didn't work.

After a good time searching Google and trying to fix it, I have added the correct lib and include folders to the OpenCVConfig.make (at /opt/local/share/opencv here). Well, this is the output when I try to make it:

```
$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/carlosagarie/dropbox/code/c++/opencv

$ make
Linking CXX executable teste
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      _main in teste.cc.o
  "cv::imshow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in teste.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [teste] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/teste.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Trying to find out why it said **ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**, I looked at my libraries folder (/opt/local/lib) and used the file command:

```
libopencv_calib3d.2.2.0.dylib:    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

The same for all the other libs. So, I assume that it's not a problem with them. But, why isn't ld working them? I really don't know what to do.

The code is the same as in the tutorial presented earlier. My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( teste )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( teste teste )
target_link_libraries( teste ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are following the 2.3.x guide, but the link error is referring to 2.2.0. Which version are you using?

Have you tried compiling it manually?

With something like this:

Assuming `OPENCV_ROOT` is set to your install location (e.g., /opt/local)

```
g++ -I$OPENCV_ROOT/include -L$OPENCV_ROOT/lib -lopencv_core2.2.0 -lopencv_calib3d2.2.0 -c test.cpp
```

If that doesn't work, have you tried running `ldconfig` as root? Is the install location for the opencv libraries setup in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (If not, you need to do this **first** before `ldconfig` will do anything useful)?

Edit you answer with updates to these questions. And, I'll try to help you with the rest.

**EDIT :**
You might also try adding this to your ~/.profile and see it fixes it:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

Have you tried following this [guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port) starting from Section 2 with XCode?

Comment: I tried to compile it using

`g++ -I/include -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui teste.cc -o teste`

And the error is the same, "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64".

I'm using a Mac, so there's no ldconfig utility nor a /etc/ld.so.conf file. 

I'm thinking about a clean reinstall - deleting all the .dylibs and the include stuff is enough? Or is there any other files for me to take care?

Thanks a lot for your help.