# error installing OpenCV 2.4.3 Mac OSX Linking CXX

Tags: macos, opencv, linker, installation

I am trying to install OpenCV 2.4.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 by using MacPort. I installed opencv 2.4.4 through homebrew. But when I tried linking the libraries I keep getting an error when compiling the program through qmake (Qt): `symbols not found architecture _x86-64`. So now I am trying to install opencv 2.4.3 through MacPort but I keep getting the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib
ld: library not found for -lmp3lame
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.3.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it would be nice to see more information about your installation process: are you installing it using some documentation? or may be you installing it using brew or else? Right now all I can say is it can't find mp3lame library.

Comment: I just edited my post. I hope this can give you more information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I formatted my hard drive, thus deleting everything. I re-downloaded Qt Creater and its corresponding libraries for mac and installed OpenCV through MacPorts. Everything went smoothly and I am now using OpenCV on Qt. I guess I might have done something wrong the first time. Thanks to everyone who tried helping me. I appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

- With opencv installed using homebrew you should probably add additional search paths to your makefile (note that opencv must be installed without --32-bit flag). Also you can try to install it with flag --with-qt (see `brew info opencv`). Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909878/linking-opencv-2-3-program-in-mac-os-x-lion-symbols-not-found-for-architectur) - may be it is your case.
- For the errors during installation via macports: just install all dependencies first. In your case probably `sudo port install lame`.
- Also you can install it by yourself using [install guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide), [this](http://blog.cingusoft.org/howto-install-opencv-on-mac-os-x-lion)(OS X 10.7) or [this](http://tech.enekochan.com/2012/07/27/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-ffmpeg-support-in-mac-os-x-10-8/)(OS X 10.8) tutorial for example
- Check related questions in the right column on this page - they also can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your linker is telling you that:

1. Qt was not installed on your machine (or at least in a location where the shell was not aware of) ;
2. `lame` (and the associated library) is not installed on your system. If it is, then it is located (as per macports standards) installed in the `/opt/` directory, which is not in the search path by default. You have to modifiy your `.bashrc` or your `.profile` file to add it.

In order to install OpenCV on MacOS, I would definitely recommend using either compile from the source (on github) or installing from [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).
In the first case you control each option passed to cmake in order to fit your system, while in the second you have a more reactive community (according to my experience) to solve installation issues and stick with the latest releases.